# Kenmore glass-top oven range shorting out

Tags: electrical, oven, range

My husband and I own a Kenmore slide-in glass-top oven, model 790-46359400.  Recently, my back right burner stopped working, so we ordered a replacement and put that in. The new burner works fine, but now we have a bigger problem: using any of the four burners for a few minutes results in a loud POP from the active burner and the stovetop shorting out.

When we look at the burner we were using, we see scorch marks on the wiring and harness. While replacing the original faulty burner, we removed the glass top itself from the oven instead of removing the assembly underneath. We think that the newly-loosened top is bumping/pressing on something.

Replacing this stove is not cheap.  Anyone have any idea why we're getting the short, and what we could do to fix it? We have some ATV high temperature sealant coming from Amazon that we plan to use to reattach the glass top. Is that enough, or do we need to do something else?

It's practically identical to [this one on Sears.com](http://www.sears.com/kenmore-4.6-cu-ft-slide-in-electric-range/p-02242539000P?sellerId=SEARS&prdNo=1&blockNo=1&blockType=G1&sid=ISx106xdGx&psid=15x8271437&knshCrid=4825225&k_clickID=2f7f5501-46f8-42b3-9700-7feec57acde6&gclid=Cj0KEQiA39_BBRD0w-_rmOrc__8BEiQA-ETxXb0alFiy6ZKftzNiLUpvC22E6x-NQzyki5kFvzn0j-EaAt6Z8P8HAQ#).

Thank you in advance!

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Can you post photos of the area around the recently replaced burner?

Answer (score 1):

The damage to the wiring in your third picture is the reason the stove is shorting out.  You can see the metal wire terminal has melted.  This is because it is much too close to the black metal frame that is surrounding it.

When using the stove, the movement and vibration cause the terminal to touch the frame and short out.  You will have to move this terminal away from the frame to solve this problem.

However, from the picture it looks like the terminal is compromised.  Due to parts of it being melted, and the carbon build up from the arc flashes, this could now be a poor electrical connection, which could lead to further issues/failures of this burner down the road.

You will likely have to crimp a new female sta-kon connector onto the wire connected to this terminal, and at a minimum clean the carbon off of the terminal itself.  If the terminal is damaged to a point where the wire does not attach snuggly, you may have to replace the element.

Comment: Actually, until the stove shorted out, the wiring was perfectly fine. The back right burner, in particular, was brand-new. No damage whatsoever, until it later popped.

Also, we're not actually using the stove when it pops. I turned the stove on for about ten minutes today and just left it, to see what would happen. Then it popped all on its own.

I'll talk to my husband about sta-kon connectors. We didn't know what those were called. If we can replace them, that would be great!

Comment: That is what I'm saying.  In replacing the burner, that terminal was placed too close to the black metal frame.  The movement of using the stove causes it to touch the frame, creating the short.  Moving that terminal away from the frame will prevent the short (ie, bending it slightly, or adjusting the position of the burner/ceramic box the terminal comes out of.

Edit: Sta-kon is a brand name, that I associate with female spade terminals.  Sta-kon makes a variety of different wire terminals.  Kind of like calling a tissue Kleenex.